# Retrieving list of websites in IIS7.5 vs IIS8. Why is the process taking so long on IIS8 (2012 Windows RS Server)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, iis-8

We have 2 projects running on 2 different servers that are using the same code. One server is a 2008 R2 server and the second is a 2012 R2 server.

One of the main functions of the project is to retrieve a list of websites from IIS and then use that list to perform various functions on the websites.

We recently were forced to update all of our servers to 2012 because Microsoft stopped supporting 2008. Everything works fine, except when it comes to trying to retrieve the list of websites from IIS. On the 2008 server the process takes about 1 sec to get the list of 200 websites. On the 2012 server the process takes about 30 - 40 seconds and it's w3wp.exe process uses about 3 times as much memory for the exact same set of websites

Does anyone have any idea on what we could be doing wrong? Or what we can do to fix this?

We have written a test below so that you can see our code and diagnose what may be causing the issue.

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

**Instructions:**
1. Copy GetSiteList.aspx to the root of the project

2. Modify GetSiteList.aspx file for correct settings:

   private string ServerName = "Your Server Name";
   private string LoginId = @"Your Login Id";
   private string Password = "Your Password";
3. Modify Web.config file for correct settings.
   Make sure you have "impersonate" and also assemblies reference for "System.DirectoryServices"
4. Open page http://[your-server-name]/GetSiteList.aspx

**GetSiteList.aspx**

```
﻿<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.DirectoryServices"%>
<script runat="server">
    private string ServerName = "your server name";
    private string LoginId = @"your login id";
    private string Password = "your password";
    private class SiteInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Root { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divSites.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void cmdRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
         List<SiteInfo> siteList = new List<SiteInfo>();
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry service = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + ServerName + "/W3SVC", LoginId, Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing);
        string className = service.SchemaClassName.ToString();
        if (className.EndsWith("Service"))
        {
            DirectoryEntries sites = service.Children;
            foreach (DirectoryEntry site in sites)
            {
                if (site.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
                {
                    SiteInfo info = new SiteInfo();
                    info.Id = Convert.ToInt32(site.Name);
                    if (info.Id <= 1)
                        continue;
                    info.Name = site.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString();
                    foreach (DirectoryEntry v in site.Children)
                    {
                        if (v.Name == "ROOT")
                        {
                            info.Root = v.Properties["Path"].Value.ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    siteList.Add(info);
                }
            }
        }
        TimeSpan executeTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        rptSites.DataSource = siteList;
        rptSites.DataBind();
        divSites.Visible = true;
        lblTime.Text = "&nbsp;Elapsed execution time: " + executeTime.ToString();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdRun" OnClick="cmdRun_Click" Text="Get Site List" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="divSites" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Root</td>
                </tr>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptSites" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblId" text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' /></td>
                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td></td>
                            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRoot" text='<%# Eval("Root") %>' /></td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web Config:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="Your Login Id" password="Your Password"></identity>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">        
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```